# Average per quarter hour

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with these columns:

```
Id, Method, DateTime, time taken
```

Ex

```
1, Done,      2014-06-22 08:18:00.000, 2000
2, Not Done,  2014-06-23 04:15:00.000, 5000
3, Done,      2014-06-23 14:15:00.000, 6000
```

I want to have a result set as, "average time taken by DONE methods in each 15 min interval between 8AM to 15PM"

Please guide me on how to proceed on this, I am not sure if cursor fits in this req.

Comment: What is time Taken? seconds, minutes, hours?

Comment: that is mili seconds..but in database kept as BIGINT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CTE to generate a list of quarters.  Then `left join` to look up the run times per quarter.  A `group by` will allow you to calculate the average.

In SQL Server 2012, the `time` type is available, and you can:

```
; with  quarters as
        (
        select  cast('08:00' as time) as time
        union all
        select  dateadd(minute, 15, time)
        from    quarters
        where   time <= '14:30'
        )  
select  q.time
  ,       avg(rt.time_taken) as avg_time_taken
from    quarters q
left join
        RunTime rt
on      q.time <= cast(rt.dt as time)
        and cast(rt.dt as time) < dateadd(minute, 15, q.time)
        and method = 'Done'
group by
        q.time
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8f8c9/16/0)

For SQL Server 2008R2 and earler, you can use integer math instead:

```
; with  quarters as
        (
        select  8*60 as min
        union all
        select  min + 15
        from    quarters
        where   min < 15*60
        )  
select  q.min / 60 as hour
,       q.min % 60 as minute
,       avg(rt.time_taken) as avg_time_taken
from    quarters q
left join
        (
        select  datepart(minute, dt) +
                60 * datepart(hour, dt) as min
        ,       time_taken
        from    RunTime
        where   method = 'Done'
        ) rt
on      q.min <= rt.min and rt.min < q.min + 15
group by
        q.min;
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8f8c9/17/0)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you want, but here ist the code:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test(
id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Method nvarchar(50),
[Datetime] datetime,
timeTaken Bigint
)

CREATE TABLE #Result(
[Between] datetime,
[And] datetime,
[Avg] bigint)

INSERT INTO #Test (Method,Datetime,timeTaken)
VALUES(
'Done', '2014-06-22 08:18:00.000', 2000),
('Not Done', '2014-06-23 04:15:00.000', 5000),
('Done', '2014-06-23 14:15:00.000', 6000)

DECLARE @MaxTime datetime,@StartTime datetime,@Next datetime

SELECT @MaxTime = MAX([datetime]),
@StartTime = MIN([datetime])
FROM #TEST

WHILE @StartTime <= @MaxTime
BEGIN

SET @Next = (SELECT Dateadd(MINUTE,15,@StartTime))

INSERT INTO #Result
SELECT @StartTime AS [Between], @Next AS [And],AVG(timeTaken) AS [AVG]
FROM #Test 
WHERE [Datetime] Between @StartTime AND @Next
AND Method = 'Done'

SET @StartTime = @Next

END

SELECT * FROM #Result

DROP TABLE #Test
DROP TABLE #Result
```

You can now set a where to the Select * from #result in which you can say between 8 AM and 3 PM
Please let me know if this is what you want

Etienne